# Google Cloud Platform admin panel IP restriction

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is it possible to restrict access to cloud.google.com to specific IPs?
When I create a principal I'm giving it a specific role, but I would like to give access for that user/s only if it log in from specific IP.

[EDIT] To clarify, access should be restricted to the whole project. F.e. I limit access to only IP1. User "A" logs in to cloud.google.com, chooses project and if he logged from IP2, he won't see anything ("you don't have access .." message, same as the role based restrictions if you go when you shouldn't).
If he connects from IP2 he should have access to everything he's role gives him.

Only limits I can find in documentation (also the IAP pointed by Arden) are restrictions **TO** something (app, resource, etc.) not **FROM** something.

So the question is, is it even possible to do something like that.

Comment: No, you cannot restrict access to https://cloud.google.com. Please edit your question and clearly state your objective. You can restrict access to **some** resources. State which ones in your question. Read the documentation for Organization Policy Constraints, IAM Conditions, and IAM Conditional Role Bindings to understand your options.

Comment: I edited the question so it should be more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

You need implement [Identity-Aware Proxy (IAP) : Authenticate users with Google Accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authenticate-users-google-accounts#enabling_iap)

### When to use IAP

Use IAP when you want to enforce access control policies for applications and resources. IAP works with signed headers or the App Engine standard environment Users API to secure your app. With IAP, you can set up group-based application access: a resource could be accessible for employees and inaccessible for contractors, or only accessible to a specific department.

Comment: You mean restrict access to the Google Cloud Console ?

Comment: I edited the question. Basically yes, but I mean the project, not the google console itself.